# Force ignore duplicate symbols?

Tags: c++, c, macos, ld

I am building some legacy code from projects that uses static libraries. Now, I get lots of errors like this:

```
ld: warning: option -m is obsolete and being ignored
ld: duplicate symbol <function name>
```

Is there a way to force through the build. From what I can see the "duplicate" functions are identical, it's just the build process thats gone haywire. The project is really large (and a mess of legacy c and c++ code) and I really want to avoid spending hours investigating the build process. Is there a "quick fix"? I really only need to run this program once, so I can live with (some) stability issues.

Answer (score 6):

From the GNU `ld` man-page:

```
       --allow-multiple-definition
       -z muldefs
           Normally when a symbol is defined multiple times, the linker will
           report a fatal error. These options allow multiple definitions and
           the first definition will be used.
```

Comment: I presume this is "safe" when and only when the duplicate symbol definitions are identical? It would be nice to have a more careful "--allow-identical-definitions" that would still fatal if multiple distinct definitions existed

Answer (score 1):

A search in `man ld` (for "duplicate"), on my system, brought this up:

> ```
>    --traditional-format
>        For some targets, the output of ld is different in some ways from
>        the output of some existing linker.  This switch requests ld to use
>        the traditional format instead.
>
>        For example, on SunOS, ld combines duplicate entries in the symbol
>        string table.  This can reduce the size of an output file with full
>        debugging information by over 30 percent.  Unfortunately, the SunOS
>        "dbx" program can not read the resulting program ("gdb" has no
>        trouble).  The --traditional-format switch tells ld to not combine
>        duplicate entries.
> ```

Try it. Maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: Which platform is that for? That option is not available on Mac OS X. However, I tried it without success on an Ubuntu machine. From the man page it sounds more like it has to do with debug symbols.

Comment: This is the output of `man ld` on my Debian machine (ld v 2.21.0.20110327). I didn't test it. Sorry it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MinGW-W64 then you can use the ld option

`LDFLAGS="-Wl,-allow-multiple-definition"`