# Allow a specific function to be undefined, as long as it's never called at runtime

Tags: c++, mingw, weak-symbol

I have several source files, which are compiled and linked into several executables. Some executables don't link some of the files.

I'm getting `undefined reference` errors, because the calls to the missing functions are still present in the code, even though they will never happen at runtime. I'm looking for a way to disable those errors (and if the call actually happens, crashing is fine).

Ultimately, this boils down to following: (I want this code to build and run)

**`1.h`**

```
#pragma once

struct A
{
    /*??*/ void foo();
    /*??*/ void bar();
};
```

**`1.cpp`**

```
#include "1.h"

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.foo(); // foo!

    volatile bool f = false;
    if (f)
        a.bar();
}
```

**`2.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "1.h"

void A::foo() {std::cout << "foo\n";}
```

This obviously gives me `undefined reference` errors.

I want to support MSVC, MinGW, Linux, and Emscripten.

For Linux and Emscripten, I found that adding `__attribute__((__weak__))` to the declarations (at `/**/`) does exactly what I want (no linker errors, calling an undefined function crashes at runtime).

For MSVC, I found this pragma: `_Pragma("comment(linker, \"/alternatename:??=fallback\")")`, where `??` is the mangled name of such a function, and `fallback` is the name of the fallback symbol, which can be something like `extern "C" const std::nullptr_t fallback = nullptr;`.

I can use a macro to insert the function name into the pragma, so I end up with:

```
struct A
{
    MAYBE_UNDEFINED(mangled_name_of_foo) void foo();
    MAYBE_UNDEFINED(mangled_name_of_bar) void bar();
};
```

, which expands to the pragma on MSVC, and to `__attribute__((__weak__))` otherwise.

But I'm still having issues with MinGW. Adding `__attribute__((__weak__))` like on Linux doesn't work, the resulting application segfaults on `a.foo();` ([bug report](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/18176)).

It starts working if the definitions don't see `__attribute__((__weak__))` (so it needs to be conditionally disabled with macros), but I really don't like the syntax.

Having to define a unique macro per source file to conditionally add `__weak__` is annoying, so I'm looking for a more bearable syntax to do the same thing. Ideally just a macro I can just add to the declarations and/or definitions.

---

I also tried "weak aliases" on MinGW, but no cigar:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
#endif

struct A
{
    FOO void foo();
    FOO void bar();
};
```

Then, in a separate source file:

```
extern "C" void fallback() {}
#define FOO __attribute__((__weak__, __alias__("fallback")))
#include "1.h"
```

This still gives me undefined references, unless I add `__weak__` to the declarations as well, at which point the code links, but crashes at `a.foo();` (which makes it no different to not having weak aliases at all, and just leaving weak functions undefined).

Comment: You could make `foo` and `bar` null function pointers then have wherever those functions are defined set the pointers on load?

Comment: The code provided **has** to link `A::bar`.  If it were changed to `constexpr bool f = false;` and `if constexpr (f) a.bar();` then it won't link `A::bar`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm trying to make this change as unintrusive as possible. I'm trying to add this to an existing codebase, so I'm trying to write a simple macro I can slap onto those functions, without forcing my teammates to write the code to load each individual function pointer.

Comment: @Eljay Well, and I don't want to link it. That's the question. I found ways to do that on all platforms I care about, except one.

Comment: I guess having a "fallback lib" implementing the functions and linking it last is not an option for you...

Comment: @fabian Perhaps it could be. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: The gnu linker scans from left to right and uses the first matching symbol it finds so by putting fall backs on the end of your linker command they would only be used to clear up any remaining unresolved symbols

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried it, but LD gives me duplicate definition errors. [Here's the code](https://pastebin.com/2Qh6aa8U), and the command is: `rm -f lib2.a lib3.a && g++ -c 2.cpp && g++ -c 3.cpp && ar cr lib2.a 2.o && ar cr lib3.a 3.o && g++ 1.cpp -L. -l2 -l3`. I think I remember reading something about linker ignoring duplicate symbols, but that was for the MSVC linker, not GNU.

Comment: @fabian Also pinging you in case you know what's going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669328/force-ignore-duplicate-symbols

Comment: @AlanBirtles I see, this is unfortunate.